# How to add a pdf image to a gnuplot plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have an image in PDF format and I want to add to an existing gnuplot plot.

My current code is like:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color solid font "Nimbus Roman No9 L" 35
set output '|epstopdf --filter > Patterns.pdf'
set size 1.8,1.8
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
plot 'Patterns.dat' using ($2/2.90):xtic(1) title col fs pattern 3
```

and the pdf file is stored in image.pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done, at least with the `epslatex` terminal. First, for my example, I am going to generate a pdf file which is a gnuplot-generated figure:

```
set term epslatex standalone
set output "plot1.tex"
plot sin(x)
```

Now, outside gnuplot, I generate the pdf file (named `plot1.pdf`):

```
pdflatex plot1.tex
```

which looks like this:

[image]

To embed this into a gnuplot graph, I use again the `epslatex` terminal and embed `plot1.pdf` as I would do with any pdf file in a latex document, using the `\includegraphics[]{}` environment, with a gnuplot `label`:

```
set term epslatex standalone
set output "plot2.tex"
set label at graph 0.75,0.25 '\includegraphics[width=2cm]{plot1.pdf}'
plot x
```

And, again run `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex plot2.tex
```

that generates `plot2.pdf`, which looks like this:

[image]

By changing the location of the `label` you can change the location of the embedded pdf; by changing the `width` you can change, guess what, the width of the embedded pdf.